# dictionary help for python using a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one question about writing a dictionary given a file. I have done the coding but I am really confused.  The parameter name is "`load_words: (file)`" and the output expected is "`dict of {str: list of strs}`".

The description of the problem given is:

> "The open file contains one lowercase word per line. Return a dictionary in which each key is a single lowercase letter and each value is a list of the words from the file that start with that letter. Only letters that one or more words from the file start with appear as keys in the dictionary.  "

I am trying to write my code for

```
def load_words(file1):
```

I really don't know how to approach this question any help would be appreciated any hints or even a complete solution and I could work backwards.

NOTE: IS NOT A HOMEWORK PROBLEM. I have a midterm in 2 days and I am trying to do the past midterms so please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as follows:

```
def load_words(file1):
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in file1:
        line = line.strip()
        if line not in answer[line[0]]:
            answer[line[0]].append(line)
    return answer
```

However, for your midterm, your professor might be expecting this answer:

```
def load_words(file1):
    answer = {}
    for line in file1:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] in answer: # or in answer.keys() or in answer.iterkeys()
            if line not in answer[line[0]]:
                answer[line[0]].append(line)
        else:
            answer[line[0]] = [line] # or answer[line[0]] = []; answer[line[0]].append(line)
    return answer
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I would suggest not using defaultdict when you are learning the basics. You are avoiding the concept of how to check the dict for the key

Comment: Granted. I've added the second solution.

Comment: This is just an example of how to use a dictionary and list value right? Its not really the solution to the actual problem.

Comment: I intended for it to be the real solution. Do you see a bug?

Comment: It doesn't check for lower case words? All it does it grab the first letter of the line. Essentially this example indexes every line by the first letter of that line.

Comment: @jdi: The question says "The open file contains one lowercase word per line." - no case check is required.

Comment: LOL I am an idiot. I read it as "Each line contains at least one lower case word". Dont know how that happened. You get a +1 for putting up with me being an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

Just write out the logic you need to do in pseudocode, and then go back over it to fill in the real code:

*Thanks @mhawke for pointing out that I misread the problem*

```
function load_words(file)
  for each line in the file
    get the first letter of the line (word)
    lowercase the letter
    if dict[letter] does not yet exist
        create an empty list at this key
    add word to list in dict with first letter as key
  return the dict
```